# C# output letter grade from a range using doubles

Tags: c#, double

It appears my teacher wants the class to use double to solve this problem. I am having difficulty getting it to take. I'm sure it's someting simple that I'm missing but I want to see what others think.

```
public char Test4(double grade)

    {
        // TODO: Write code here to compute an answer.
        //       Return the answer from this function.
        //       Read the lab document for detailed instructions.
    }
```

I've tried using if else statements and to no luck. I'm not sure how to use a double for this. Please help.

Thanks.

Here's an example of what I've tried.

```
if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100)
        { 
            public char = 'A'
        }
        else if (grade >=80 && grade <90)
            {
            public char = 'B'
                        }
        return public char;
{
```

The output:
[image: Here is my output]

I've cleaned this up. Hope this helps to clarify the question.

```
    public char Test4(double grade)
    {
        // TODO: Write code here to compute an answer.
        //       Return the answer from this function.
        //       Read the lab document for detailed instructions.
        if (grade >= 90.0)
        { return 'A'; }
        else
            if (grade >= 80.0)
        { return 'B'; }
        else
            if (grade >= 73.0)
        { return 'C'; }
        else 
            if (grade >=70.0)
        { return 'D'; }
        else
            if (grade >= 0)
        { return 'F'; }
        else
            if (grade <0 )
        { return '?'; }
        else
            if (grade > 100)
        { return '?'; }
    }
```

Comment: OH here's the info from the lab document.                                                                                         "Given the grade variable, which indicates a student's numeric grade, determine which letter grade they should receive. Return the proper letter (char) as the result of this test. Do not worry about rounding the grade. Use the following table to indicate which letter corresponds to which grades.

Comment: Please show us something besides a copy of the homework problem. What have you tried? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: please add more details to your question

Comment: You can remove `public char =` (that part doesn't make sense and likely throws an error) and just 'return' the letter grade (i.e. `return 'A'`).  There are improvements you could make to your code, but I'd imagine your `if` statements work if you just return the letter grade in the statement.

Comment: { double A = (grade <= 90.0 && grade >= 100);
            return "A";

Comment: I thought that too and it still doesn't give me an outuput for any of the ranges for when I run the program. Even if the integers fall into that rang.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment, but @Broom's answer is what I was getting at.  Does that work for you?

Comment: By the way, you should be able to do this without two tests in each `if` statement.  For the first, `grade >= 90` is good enough (if someone has 101, she/he should get an `A`).  After that, since you are using `else`, the only test you need is `grade >= 80` (since 90 and above is already covered by the first test), `grade >= 70`, etc.

Comment: Looks like you're getting some useful answers below.  I'll just add this -- you should be able to take questions like this directly to your professor/teacher's assistant.  Especially in a beginner/intro course, it's expected that you'll have a lot of issues to work out, and nothing beats an expert sitting beside you to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning "public char", you need to either return it in place, or store the value in a variable.

example 1

```
if (grade >= 90)
{
    return 'A';
}
else if ....
{
    //copy for each letter grade above F
}
else 
{
    return 'F';
}
```

example 2

```
char gradeLetter = 'F';
if (grade >= 90)
{
    gradeLetter = 'A';
}
else if ....
{
    //copy for each letter grade above F
}

return gradeLetter;
```

Comment: I'll add a screenshot to show what I've done and the "run" window.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QF681OGuKvFNtFKUJxOZn6TnLsFwcvBp              Here's a link to it. Site won't let me embed an image just yet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you compile with `Test4` as written and are running and old, unimplemented version of `Test4` (hence no results). You have an error, which I'm guessing is: "not all code paths return a value."  To solve this, have a "catch all" at the end - you don't need to check if `grade` is `<0` **AND** `>100`, just return `?`.

```
...
else if(grade >= 0)
{
    return 'F';
}
// if none of the if statements were hit, you have an incorrect grade value
return '?';
```

This is should properly compile `Test4` (note, you have an error with `Test5` that needs to be fixed as well) and give you the correct results.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the compile errors.  Also note that just fixing the errors inside the `Test4` method won't be enough -- basically you need to get rid of all of the red errors in the error list before the "new" code will be compiled.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you for clarifying, @Gus!  **ALL** errors need to be gone so that you can successfully recompile.  I **think** it should just be in `Test5` since Tests 1-3 run and this should fix `Test4`.  Assuming I am correct, you can just comment everything out of `Test5` and add `return 0.0` to compile `Test4`

Comment: @Katoshia, did you get the answer?